# Encryption URL parameter not working

Tags: codeigniter, url, encryption

In my view form,

```
$encrypted_string = $this->encrypt->encode($list['id']);
```

where $list['id'] is auto increment. and URL,

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('welcome/delete?id='.$encrypted_string);?>">Delete</a>
```

In Controler,

```
 $id1 = $_GET['id'];
 $id = $this->encrypt->decode($id1);
```

In this $id i get decoded value for some value not for all value,please help me..Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$id1 = $_GET['id'];
```

Try

```
$id1 = $this->input->get('sid');
```

Remember that the param you are passing by query string should have the same name in your controller.

Also, in config.php change

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'auto';
```

Try different values until one of them works for you.

Comment: Its not working for all id value for some id value its working...like 1 5 9 12..id value its working...